# Node.js Whiteboard App for Team / Educational Collaboration

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, whiteboard

I'm looking to build/adapt a shared whiteboard app for team and educational collaboration. Draw on a board, write some text, save picture, clear board, etc. We've already got a simple chat system setup with node.js and socket.io so probably want to stay on that route.

1. What open source apps exist that might be pluggable / adaptable for this use?
2. What node.js / javascript / html5 technologies might be useful for this task?

Comment: https://github.com/katspaugh/whiteboard

Comment: https://github.com/lovasoa/whitebophir is an opensource collaborative drawing board written in node.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as node.js technologies you would need the following

- [express](http://expressjs.com/) to handle your http server
- [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to handle communication

As far as rendering on the client I would recommend

- [rapheal](http://raphaeljs.com/) as an SVG rendering

Apart from that you need some kind of database, Redis, mongoDB & CouchDB are popular.

Apart from that just write it. Any other libraries you think you might need along the way can be found on the [npm registry](http://npmjs.org/)

However I can offer some package.json examples [for my chat](https://github.com/Raynos/so642/blob/master/package.json) and [my blog](https://github.com/Raynos/raynos-blog/blob/master/package.json) to give some inspiration as to what libraries are useful

Comment: I've used express and socket.io. Raphael looks cool. Love to see an example to work from for drawing stuff with node.js

Comment: I wrote a prototype somewhere. A couple of hours of hacking should do. A quick google search for "node.js whiteboard" should get you started.

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251977/client-or-server-side-html5-canvas-rendering-for-a-node-js-whiteboard-application

Answer (score 3):

Another open source whiteboard in Node.js is here

https://github.com/Imaginea/matisse

website: http://www.thematisse.org

Comment: have you tried this one? I am facing the following problem Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:8000/auth/google/callback did not match a registered redirect URI, I have given redirect uri in google as http://localhost:800 only

Answer (score 1):

Open Source Whiteboard in NodeJs

https://github.com/opinsys/walma